# Find the cdf of $f(x, y) = \frac{3}{2\pi} \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

$X$ and $Y$ are random variables with the joint density function $$f(x, y) = \frac{3}{2\pi} \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}, \quad x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$$

[image]

Find the cdf $F(x, y)$. To do this, we need to compute the integral

$$ \int_{-1}^{x} \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{y} \frac{3}{2\pi} \sqrt{1-u^2-v^2} dv du .$$

The only way I know how to integrate functions of this form is using the substitution $ v = \sqrt{1-u^2}\sin{\theta} $, $ dv = \sqrt{1-u^2}\cos{\theta}d\theta$.

My attempt:

$\theta = \arcsin(\frac{v}{\sqrt{1-u^2}})$, giving

$$\int_{-1}^{x} \int_{\arcsin(-\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{1-u^2}})}^{\arcsin(\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-u^2}})} \frac{3}{2\pi} \sqrt{1-u^2-(\sqrt{1−u^2}\sin{\theta})^2} \sqrt{1−u^2}cos{\theta}d\theta du$$

$$=\int_{-1}^{x} \frac{3}{2\pi} (1−u^2) \int_{\arcsin(-\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{1-u^2}})}^{\arcsin(\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-u^2}})} cos^2{\theta}d\theta du$$

$$=\int_{-1}^{x} \frac{3}{2\pi} (1−u^2) \int_{\arcsin(-\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{1-u^2}})}^{\arcsin(\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-u^2}})} \frac{1}{2}[1+cos(2\theta)]d\theta du$$

$$=\int_{-1}^{x} \frac{3}{4\pi} (1−u^2) [\theta+\frac{1}{2}\sin(2\theta)]_{\arcsin(-\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{1-u^2}})}^{\arcsin(\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-u^2}})} du$$

At this point the integral got really messy to deal with. Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: a cdf is tied to a random variable. Is f(x,y) random?

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are random variables with the joint density function $f(x, y)$.

Comment: So you are getting the cdf of what random variable?

Comment: Both, I'm looking for the joint cdf of $f(x, y)$ i. e. $F(x, y)$. The cdf of only one variable would be a marginal cdf, either $F_X(x)$ or $F_Y(y)$.

Comment: @Canardini $f(x,y)$ is the joint DF of $X$ and $Y$, and the question is about the joint cumulative distribution function of $X$ and $Y$: $$ \int_{-\infty}^x \int_{-\infty}^y{\rm d}x{\rm d}y~ f(x,y)$$

Comment: Got it , my mistake ! thanks